# Furthest points of a point in kNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

In the documentation of [kNN classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html), there is a method [`kneighbors`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#kneighbors), which returns k nearest neighbors. I am interested in how to return k furthest neighbors in such classifier elegantly?

Comment: — I really like that you're looking for the furthest neighbor. Could you please tell me what is the reason for that?

Comment: @Aerodynamika Outlier detection is an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, there is no such capability.

You need to remember that for performance, there would be a tree to get the closest neighbors. Trying to find the furthest means going through the full tree, basically computing all distance.

So don't use kNN in that case, just compute distances and sort them.

Comment: Just to make sure, do I need to worry about which specific tree does a kNN classifier use?

Comment: No, any tree will probably make it impossible to retrieve the furthest neighbors. And kNN tree for closest neighbors are optimized for this task.

Comment: It depends, most spatial indexes do not support farthest neighbor queries out of the box, but most spatial indexes can easily be modified to do this efficiently without having to search the whole tree. See my answer for a reference.

Answer (score 2):

Many spatial indexes (quadtrees, R-Trees, ...) can be easily modified to support farthest neighbor queries. One common algorithm is described [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/cmsc420/ContentBook/FormalNotes/neighbor.pdf) (see Section 4.5). However, most do not support it out of the box.

If you are using a kd-tree, then, as the other poster said, it may may not possible to do this efficiently.

Another option may be the CoverTree, I don't think Hjaltason/Samet's algorithm will work there, but it is unlikely that you have to search the whole tree.

I'm also not sure which options scikit-learn provides, if you really must use it.

Comment: Is there other libraries you would recommend?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know machine learning libraries that well. I also do not know spatial index libraries for python (I know some Java libraries, but probably without furthest neighbor). Furthest neighbor searches are somewhat 'rare', so you may have to adapt existing libraries/code yourself.